RHEL 9.4 cannot install the best update candidate for package remi-release-9.4-2.el9.remi.noarch
I am using RHEL 9.4, and I attempt to update the RHEL packages using sudo dnf update, the output is:
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 2:37:30 ago on Tue 31 Dec 2024 08:04:20 HKT.
Error: 
 Problem: cannot install the best update candidate for package remi-release-9.4-2.el9.remi.noarch
  - nothing provides (redhat-release >= 9.5 or centos-stream-release >= 9) needed by remi-release-9.5-1.el9.remi.noarch from remi-safe
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

Then I add --nobest flag as instructed, the output is:
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 2:36:48 ago on Tue 31 Dec 2024 08:04:20 HKT.
Dependencies resolved.

 Problem: cannot install the best update candidate for package remi-release-9.4-2.el9.remi.noarch
  - nothing provides (redhat-release >= 9.5 or centos-stream-release >= 9) needed by remi-release-9.5-1.el9.remi.noarch from remi-safe
=====================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                  Architecture                       Version                                     Repository                             Size
=====================================================================================================================================================================
Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
 remi-release                             noarch                             9.5-1.el9.remi                              remi-safe                              30 k

Transaction Summary
=====================================================================================================================================================================
Skip  1 Package

Nothing to do.
Complete!

Why would this package be unavailable to update? and how to fix it?
Ultimately, I would like to upgrade RHEL from 9.4 to 9.5 using sudo dnf upgrade command, but I am unable to do so due to the problem above.



nothing provides (redhat-release >= 9.5 or centos-stream-release >= 9) needed by remi-release-9.5-1.el9.remi.noarch from remi-safe


Message is clear, you need 9.5
This is not a blocker, this package is skipped.

Ultimately, I would like to upgrade RHEL from 9.4 to 9.5 using sudo dnf upgrade command,

Do the upgrade.
This is explained in the FAQ, "older version are not supported"
Especially: some packages are built against OpenSSL 3.2 (new in 9.5), so this version is required.

How do I do the upgrade? Supposingly, upgrading from 9.4 to 9.5 needs to execute sudo dnf upgrade

"dnf update" is usually enough, excepted is dnf is configure to use "9.4" repo (instead of "9"),  may help https://access.redhat.com/solutions/238533

Also https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2761031

After I cleared the "set" minor version in the subscription manager and cleared the cache, the sudo dnf update works again. Thanks for your help.
